# Class function returning 'None'

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to learn class inheritance for OOP in python. The following code does what I want it to so far, but returns None after printing the pipe data when the function in the parent class is called. At first I didn't have the function returning the print statement, so I added in the return keyword, but that didn't get rid of the issue. I know it must be a return issue that I am overlooking. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np


class piping:
    def __init__(self, diameter, length):
        self.d = diameter
        self.len = length

    def getPipeData(self):
        return print('The pipe length is %.1fm, and the diameter is %.1fm.' % (self.len, self.d))


class hydrodynamics(piping):
    def __init__(self, diameter, length, fluid, density):
        super().__init__(diameter, length)
        self.fluid = fluid
        self.density = density

        self.volume = self.getVolume()

    def getVolume(self):
        return np.pi*self.d**2/4


sec1 = hydrodynamics(1, 10, 'water', 1000)
sec2 = hydrodynamics(0.5, 30, 'water', 1000)

print(sec1.getPipeData())
print(sec2.getPipeData())
print(sec1.volume)
print(sec2.volume)
```

This is what is being returned...(as I said, everything works fine so far, except that I am having issues with the return None)

```
The pipe length is 10.0m, and the diameter is 1.0m.
None
The pipe length is 30.0m, and the diameter is 0.5m.
None
0.7853981633974483
0.19634954084936207
```

The output I was expecting is:

```
The pipe length is 10.0m, and the diameter is 1.0m.
The pipe length is 30.0m, and the diameter is 0.5m.
0.7853981633974483
0.19634954084936207
```

Comment: `print` returns `None`, what else did you expect it to return?

Comment: @UnholySheep, what do you mean? The 'print' statement returned by 'getPipeData' will always return 'None'?

Comment: Please update your question with the output that you require from your code.

Comment: The return value from `print()` is always `None`. You are returning this `None` from `getPipeData()`

Comment: @quamrana I understand now! I need to just call the function at the end of the code instead of printing the function. Thanks!

Comment: In order to actually return the string you remove the `print`, e.g.: `return 'The pipe length is %.1fm, and the diameter is %.1fm.' % (self.len, self.d)`

Comment: @UnholySheep, that is exactly what it was changed to. I understand why it was printing and returning none. This is all a learning experience for me, and I really, really appreciate your input! Have a great day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that really is what you want from your program then you could change your calling code to this:

```
sec1.getPipeData()
sec2.getPipeData()
print(sec1.volume)
print(sec2.volume)
```

However, better is to not `print` anything inside member functions. If you change your class to the following, you can keep your driving code as is.

```
class piping:
    def __init__(self, diameter, length):
        self.d = diameter
        self.len = length

    def getPipeData(self):
        return 'The pipe length is %.1fm, and the diameter is %.1fm.' % (self.len, self.d)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your comment above helped me to see that. I really appreciate the help! Also, this is exactly what I changed the code to.

Comment: Also, thank you for the heads up on needing to include what my expected output is. Next time I have a question, I will be sure to do that the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You should leave out the `print` statement in your definition of `getPipeData` and only return the string.

**OR:**

Call `sec1.getPipeData()` without the `print`, since the `print` will be executed when you call `sec1.getPipeData()`

Comment: Thank you! @quamrana's comment above helped me to see that. I really appreciate the help!